# Python Pandas Mixed Boolean Yes/True and NaN Columns

Tags: python, import, pandas

I am doing a health science course where R or Stata are recommended.  I'm trying to use Python / Numpy / Pandas instead as I wish to use it in future for financial time series analysis.

The data was Stata format so I copied the fields and saved them as a `CSV`.
All fields imports are fine except that there are a number of columns of Yes/No some of which have blank fields.

Import command is

```
fhs = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('F:\\BioStatistics\\fds\\fhs_c2.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
```

If there is a blank field the dtype is object (makes sense)

If there are no blanks some columns convert to `TRUE/FALSE`, others leave as `Yes/No` but dtype is bool.  Any idea why?

I want all to by one dtype and expressed one way for viewing + stat analysis.

I have achieve this by adding a row at the beginning with blank cells for the Boolean columns that had no spaces - so everything becomes an object.  Then I use 
`fhs = fhs.drop([1002])` to drop that row and data types are still good.

I'd love to save it without this row and just be able to load the data each time with "correct" types but don't know if it possible when some of the columns will have all yes or no, and some will have blank cells.  Is it possible?

Thanks, Sorry about the newbie question.

### Example:

Importing

```
      C1    C2    C3

R1   Yes   Yes    No

R2    No    No    No

R3   Yes         Yes

R4   Yes   Yes   Yes
```

first column comes into df as Yes, No, Yes, Yes  type bool xxxx below

2nd   column comes into df as Yes, No, NaN, Yes  type object

3rd   column comes into df as FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE  type bool

Damn.  Just checked.  I was wrong.  If its yes and no then the column type is object.

I'd like to tell it when importing to make them all object and stick with yes and no because:
1.  I think the 2nd column must be object (as its mixed otherwise i think)
2.  The data set is in yes / no and other class members will be looking at yes and no

### What happened when I tried the solution.

Here's my data:  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIicg.gif)

Here's the code:
    from pandas import *
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
def convert_bool(col):
    if str(col).title() ==  "True": #check for nan
        return "Yes"
    elif str(col).title() == "False":
        return "No"
    else:
        return col

fhs = pd.read_csv('F:\\BioStatistics\\fds\\StatExport.csv', converters={"death": lambda x:convert_bool(x)}, header=0, index_col=0)
```

and output [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moZQA.gif)

Comment: Please give an example of data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Example:

Importing
      C1    C2    C3
R1   Yes   Yes    No
R2    No    No    No
R3   Yes         Yes
R4   Yes   Yes   Yes

first column comes into df as Yes, No, Yes, Yes  type bool xxxx below
2nd   column comes into df as Yes, No, NaN, Yes  type object
3rd   column comes into df as FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE  type bool

Damn.  Just checked.  I was wrong.  If its yes and no then the column type is object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the converters field from pandas.read_csv

```
def convert_bool(col):
    if str(col).title() ==  "True": #check for nan
        return "YES"
    elif str(col).title() == "False":
        return "NO"
    else:
        return col
pandas.read_csv(file_in, converters={"C3": lambda x:convert_bool(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that will do it.

Comment: Sorry I cant seem to format these comments.  I've added the code and results to the end of my original post.

Comment: John, that looks good.  It looks like that because you are indexed by randid

Comment: It would be lined up if you remove index_col=0

Comment: Thanks Michael,  
Great people here.  I just need to master the board's tech.

Answer (score 2):

Note in upcoming pandas 0.9.2 (which includes a new file parser engine) you'll be able to do:

```
In [1]: paste
data = """A,B,C
Yes,No,Yes
No,Yes,Yes
Yes,,Yes
No,No,No"""

result = read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype=object)
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: result
Out[2]: 
     A    B    C
0  Yes   No  Yes
1   No  Yes  Yes
2  Yes  NaN  Yes
3   No   No   No

In [3]: result = read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype=object, na_filter=False)

In [4]: result
Out[4]: 
     A    B    C
0  Yes   No  Yes
1   No  Yes  Yes
2  Yes       Yes
3   No   No   No
```

Or even (to get a NumPy array):

```
In [5]: result = read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype='S3', na_filter=False, as_recarray=True)

In [6]: result
Out[6]: 
array([('Yes', 'No', 'Yes'), ('No', 'Yes', 'Yes'), ('Yes', '', 'Yes'),
       ('No', 'No', 'No')], 
      dtype=[('A', '|S3'), ('B', '|S3'), ('C', '|S3')])
```

Comment: Thanks Wes.  Appreciate the pointer.  Now up to Pandas 11 on Python 3.3.1 and its brilliant - thanks to the team.