# Converting strings into

Tags: python, csv, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Trying to perform a simple Linear Classification on a medical data. The sample data consists of all strings, most of the values are in 'yes', 'no' format, I want this data to be converted to integer values 1 & 0 so that I can do some statistical analysis.

Following is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv('sample-data.csv',encoding='utf-16', header=None, sep=',',names=['Temp','Occurrence','Lumbar-pain','Urine-pushing','Micturition-pains','Burning-of-urethra-swelling-of-urethra-outlet','Outcome1-Urinary-bladder','Outcome2-Nephritis-of-renal'])
```

[Click here to view Sample-data.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxed_8T6OPe4OUJ3WW9XVTlHLWc)

I tried converting after moving csv data to a dataframe, tried for a specific column using the map(), but I want this to be done for all the columns where the values are 'yes','no' strings. 
Is there any blanket method to directly convert all 'yes','no' strings to integer  1 and 0 while running read_csv

```
d = {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}
print df['Outcome1-Urinary-bladder'].map(d)
```

Looked into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947521/python-pandas-mixed-boolean-yes-true-and-nan-columns), but its not suitable for my requirement.

Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jianxun's answer looks good, but if you wanted an sklearn solution, `LabelBinarizer` does exactly what you want http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer

Comment: Converting strings into what? You should fix your title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `.replace` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['yes', 'no'], size=(5,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df

     A    B    C
0   no  yes   no
1   no  yes  yes
2  yes  yes   no
3  yes   no   no
4  yes  yes  yes


df.replace(['yes', 'no'], [1, 0])

   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  0
3  1  0  0
4  1  1  1
```

alternatively

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df=='yes', 1, 0), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

which is vectorized `numpy` method and much faster than element-wise mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, you can use the sklearn imputer. to deal with null values, later you can use the get_dummy() method of pandas

> Scountry_imputer = preprocessing.Imputer(missing_values='NaN',
>   strategy='mean', axis=0)
>
> Data = pd.get_dummies(df['column_name'])